# Integrity constraint violation while adding into database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following error when I am adding data to mysql using PHP and Ajax form:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`ncd`.`patient_med_history`, CONSTRAINT
>   `fk_patient_medication_patient1` FOREIGN KEY (`patient_id`) REFERENCES
>   `patient` (`patient_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Here are both of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ncd`.`patient` (
  `patient_id` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `patient_name_en` VARCHAR(55) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' COLLATE
  `patient_status` VARCHAR(15) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`patient_id`),
  INDEX `fk_patient_clinic1_idx` (`clinic_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_patient_clinic1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`clinic_id`)
    REFERENCES `ncd`.`clinic` (`clinic_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And here the other table where the foreign key reside:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ncd`.`patient_med_history` (
  `patient_medication_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `patient_medication` VARCHAR(55) NULL,
  `disease` VARCHAR(80) NULL,
  `patient_id` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `clinic_id` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`patient_medication_id`),
  INDEX `fk_patient_medication_patient1_idx` (`patient_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_patient_medication_patient1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`patient_id`)
    REFERENCES `ncd`.`patient` (`patient_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**PS**

**Some how 3 rows are added and after that, I've got this error and no row is added anymore**

Comment: Suggests to me that constraint was added after the  3 rows were added.

Comment: Are you trying to delete some registry on `patient_med_history` and this happens? Try to remove `ON DELETE CASCADE` from this table and repeat the operation

Answer (score 1):

When an error of **Integrity Constraint** happen , means you have a table with a field who has a **FK** to another table , so you are trying to add a value in this field that doesn't exist in the other table.

When you delete instead , you cannot delete from child who has FK if you don't delete first from the parent.